# How to pass data from url without a ? like domaintools.com/domainname.com using PHP

Tags: php, url-routing

What is the code in PHP

How to pass data from a URL using a ? is straight forward.

http://localhost/raw.php?topic=news

What is needed is to pass data like domaintools.com does just with the data after the /

news.com/football

news.com/politics

A. domaintools.com/stackoverflow.com 
B. gives the whois on file (from domaintools database) and even changing the url to fit there system
C. https://whois.domaintools.com/stackoverflow.com

I have googled many permutations of keywords, php code passing via url not a using a ? and many variations of the such with other terms like $path etc

My guess is we missing something easy and/or we just don't know the right question to ask.

Comment: Search `url rewrites`.

Comment: I think you need "url rewriting", which is just made to display in a different way the links

Comment: Also try to search fancy urls

Comment: "fancy urls" really helped with good resources for tutorials, would of never thought to type the word "fancy" as techy search term, thanks and url rewriting worked to but the results were not as detailed if that made sense.

Answer (score 1):

Using "?" is called `GET` parameter, you can use `POST` parameters to post data to an endpoint